# How to take individual objects/letters and align them horizontally?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, alignment

Is there a quick way to align 8 individually drawn letters so they are all on the same line (one not higher/lower than the other)? so far I've just eyeballed it, but is there a more efficient/precise way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Align to Bottom in the [Alignment Panel](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/moving-aligning-distributing-objects.html#align_and_distribute_objects)

[image]